# Transfer Data from Excel to PPT

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I want to transfer data from one cell only from excel to powerpoint using VBA.My current code only gives me an empty rectangle shape but there is no numbers inside.

To further explain, I want to get the data from cell A12 and then put this data as a statement on my powerpoint.

As I am still very new to VBA, I am unable to figure out how to proceed. Thank you.

The code I have used which currently only gives me a rectangle shape with no content inside:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBDuN.png)

Comment: a Range of data as you say, can be a single cell. `Range("A1")` is a single cell, still a range.

Comment: Can't you just use the VBA code you found, and set the range to that one cell? Anyway, if you provide the code that you found it will be easier to help you out. You can edit your post at any time

Comment: I have tried but I am not getting the results I want. I have added my code for reference above as well

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Range("A12").Value
```

Here is the full context:

```
Sub test()
    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim newslide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim slideCtr As Integer
    Dim tb As PowerPoint.Shape
    
    Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPT.Visible = True
    Set pres = PPT.Presentations.Open( _
        "C:\Users\GShaikh\Desktop\Process Coach certificate template.pptx")
    slideCtr = 1
    Set tb = newslide.Shapes("TextBox1")
    tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Range("A12").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Did you create a testbox in the ppt deck itself? Currently, I want to input data onto a ppt template which I already have created.